# IMAGE COMPRESSION BEFORE SUBMITING TO THE SERVER

Tags: javascript, image-processing, image-compression

I'm trying to compress images from the client side before uploading to the server.
My goal is to capture the image in a file input, Compress it, and then add the compressed image as a value in another file input field(ImageInput)  which will be submitted to the server in a POST.

The Image is being compressed, But ImageInput input does not get the value of the image. It posts an empty image

```
    <script>
     function process() {
    const file = document.querySelector("#upload").files[0];

    if (!file) return;

    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    reader.onload = function (event) {
        const imgElement = document.createElement("img");
        imgElement.src = event.target.result;

        imgElement.onload = function (e) {
            const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            const MAX_WIDTH = 400;

            const scaleSize = MAX_WIDTH / e.target.width;
            canvas.width = MAX_WIDTH;
            canvas.height = e.target.height * scaleSize;

            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            ctx.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            const srcEncoded = ctx.canvas.toDataURL(e.target, "image/jpeg");

            // you can send srcEncoded to the server
            alert(srcEncoded)
            document.querySelector("#output").src = srcEncoded;

            // my file input which I want to give a value of the compressed image
            document.getElementById('ImageInput').value = srcEncoded;


           };
        };
      }
   </script>
```

Comment: Could you explain what's not working with your current code, or better clarify your question?

Comment: The Image is being compressed, But ImageInput input does not get the value of the image. It posts an empty image